# Not implementing all the methods of an interface

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, comparator

I tried reproducing the code [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) on eclipse. I get an error telling me that I have to implement all the inherited methods (because Comparator is an interface).

> The type `new Comparator(){}` must implement the inherited abstract method `Comparator.reversed()`.

There are many of these methods and the only one I want to overwrite is compare. Do I have to implement all the other methods or is there a way to specify I don't need to implement them?
I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437097/not-implementing-all-of-the-methods-of-interface-is-it-possible) that I will have to do it because of the contractual nature of an interface, but what if I just need to change one method?

```
static Map sortByValue(Map map) {
     List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
     Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
          public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
               return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
              .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
          }
     });

    Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT**
Solved by changing the compliance level to java8 in eclipse luna. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. That compiles fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [not implementing all of the methods of interface. is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437097/not-implementing-all-of-the-methods-of-interface-is-it-possible)

Comment: Are you sure you should not use any kind of generics at all in your code? Is this for Java 1.4?

Comment: @mbomb007, you realize that OP have already linked to that question in his post?

Comment: @aioobe I get an error message on eclipse: The type new Comparator(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.reversed() then if I apply the fix, I have many functions added

Comment: This is a wild guess: I think you are using Java8 in a pre-Java8-Eclipse (i.e. pre-Luna). So Eclipse does not know that all those new Comparator methods, like `thenComparing`, have a `default` implementation.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't know exactly, I am rather new to java. I am using java 8

Comment: @tobias_k actually I am using eclipse luna and java8 and the fix proposed gives me the default implementations

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The type `new Comparator(){}` must implement the inherited abstract method `Comparator.reversed()` then if I apply the fix, I have many functions added

`Comparator.reversed` was introduced in Java 1.8 and it's a [default method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) i.e. a method that you *don't* have to override.

It seems like you have your compliance level set to pre Java 1.8 (since Eclipse asks you to override `reversed`), while using Java 1.8 API (since `Comparator` has a `reversed` method).

Make sure you either **change your API to 1.7** or **change your compliance level to 1.8**. (The latter option requires Eclipse Luna or better.)

More on Eclipse compliance level:
 [What is "compiler compliance level" in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584427/what-is-compiler-compliance-level-in-eclipse)

Comment: Just tested this, and at least in Luna, a project with compliance level 1.7 builds fine with a 1.8 JDK and does not demand for all those methods to be implemented...

Comment: Ok. Well such setup seems broken to me anyway.

Answer (score 5):

This is sort of a wild guess: I think you are using Java 8 in a pre-Java 8-Eclipse (i.e. pre-Luna). This way, Eclipse does not know that all those new Comparator methods, like `thenComparing`, have a default implementation.

[In Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), Comparator has just the method `compare`, while [in Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in has a whole lot more methods, all of which have a default implementation directly in the interface and need not to be implemented in a subclass.

I suggest you switch to the newest version of Eclipse, which should be Luna. Alternatively, you can also install a patch for Eclipse Kepler, but switching to Luna is certainly better.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an interface is to obligate the implementer of said interface to have all of the methods listed there. Now there are a few ways to got about not implementing all of the methods.

1. For every method you don't wish to implement (support) just throw [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html). An example of this sort of implementation would be the [Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html).

> To keep the number of core collection interfaces manageable, the Java platform doesn't provide separate interfaces for each variant of each collection type. (Such variants might include immutable, fixed-size, and append-only.) Instead, the modification operations in each interface are designated optional — a given implementation may elect not to support all operations. If an unsupported operation is invoked, a collection throws an UnsupportedOperationException. Implementations are responsible for documenting which of the optional operations they support. All of the Java platform's general-purpose implementations support all of the optional operations.

2. Or you could follow what the Java developers did with some of the interfaces that declare a lot of methods eg: [MouseAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html). This way you'll implement every method, but they won't be doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class may be better suited for what you are doing. Although you could just `.super()` everything.

Comment: did not mean an abstract class that implements the interface ?

Comment: no, I mean rewrite it as an abstract class, that way, you can choose what to implement. I believe java swing has a solution like this for event listeners, I just cant remember what they are called

Comment: Could you give an example please? (where shall I put the super?)

Comment: Adapter classes is what they are called

Comment: from what I read in a book. you should have an abstract class that implements the interface, but in long run, you have to implement all functions later somewhere hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You have run into an Eclipse bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390889

Basically, JAVA 1.8 introduced a brand new method Comparator.reversed(). And since you have a JAVA 1.7 or earlier code, JAVA 1.8 doesn't find the method and fails to compile.