# Interface, all methods must be abstract, but one?

Tags: java, android, interface

I have the situation:

```
public interface AlarmBroadcasterRC {
    abstract void DataIn(byte[] data);
    abstract void DataOut(byte[] data);
    abstract Boolean Drop(String id);
    abstract Boolean Connected(String id, Boolean state);
}

public class GeneralActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AlarmBroadcasterRC {
.....
}
```

But I get an error from compiler at the class declaration:
[image]

Does it mean that in Android Java an interface MUST implement first method or, if all its methods are abstract, then the class must be abstract also?

Sorry to extend the Q: I was following to one of the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835116/non-mandatory-method-implementation-of-an-interface-in-java):

Comment: Implement that method and you will get the error on the next one. You have to implement them all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class that implements an interface and is not abstract, you must implement *all* of its abstract methods, not just the first.

Comment: @VitaliPetrov In Java 9+ you can provide `default` implementations for those methods in the interface. Otherwise, there is no way; what ought to happen if the method is called, and there is no definition for what that method should do?

Answer (score 1):

In an `interface` all the `methods` are by default `abstract` you don't need to add `abstract` keyword.

when you implement an `interface` you have to implement all of it's methods or declare the class as abstract.

What you can do you can provide default implementation of the methods in `interface` if you don't want to implement in the subclass.

Example:

```
public interface AlarmBroadcasterRC {
    default void DataIn(byte[] data) { }
    default void DataOut(byte[] data) {}
    default Boolean Drop(String id) {  return false; }
    default Boolean Connected(String id, Boolean state){ return false; }
}
```

Comment: thank you!!!!!! Sohail, Louis's answer and your's are the same, and to be fair, Louis was just first .. I marked his answer as the Answer, and gave you + 1, Appreciate your help!!!